# Why does vue.js alter my JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json, vuejs2

I want to return data from my API and display it in a vue.js project. 
The data is:

```
{  
   "pages":[  
      {  
         "id":3,
         "slug":"over-mij",
         "updated_at":"2017-12-25T11:16:21+01:00",
         "created_at":"2017-12-25T10:56:21+01:00",
         "title":"Over mij",
         "content":""
      },
      {  
         "id":6,
         "slug":"mijn-cv",
         "updated_at":"2017-12-25T11:07:29+01:00",
         "created_at":"2017-12-25T11:07:29+01:00",
         "title":"Mijn cv",
         "content":null
      }
   ],
   "current_user":null
}
```

Then I'm using vue-resource to load the data from my API page in a seperate module of vuex:

```
const actions = {
    initPages({commit}) {
        Vue.resource('pages').get({}).then(function(response) {
            if (response) {
                response.json().then(data => {
                    state.pages = data;
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The problem however is when I check what's inside the state.pages, this contains:

```
{
  "pages": {
    "pages": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "slug": "over-mij",
        "updated_at": "2017-12-25T11:16:21+01:00",
        "created_at": "2017-12-25T10:56:21+01:00",
        "title": "Over mij",
        "content": ""
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "slug": "mijn-cv",
        "updated_at": "2017-12-25T11:07:29+01:00",
        "created_at": "2017-12-25T11:07:29+01:00",
        "title": "Mijn cv",
        "content": null
      }
    ],
    "current_user": null
  }
}
```

For some weird reason my JSON response is altered, I've already tried setting state.pages to data.pages and this just eliminates the first pages object but not the second one.

When I set my state.pages to data.pages[0] it does work, does anyone know why this is happening?

Even when I use mutations, I still have the same issue:

module of store.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

const state = {
    pages: []
}

const mutations = {
    'setPages' (state, pages) {
        state.pages = pages;
    }
}

const getters = {
    pages(state) {
        return state.pages;
    },
    page(state) {
        return keyword =>  state.pages.find(function(page) {
            return page.slug === keyword;
        });
    }
}

const actions = {
    initPages({commit}) {
        Vue.resource('pages').get({}).then(function(response) {
            if (response) {
                response.json().then(data => {
                    commit('setPages', data.pages);
                });
            }
        });
    }
}

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    mutations,
    actions
}
```

Comment: if you use vuex you must follow this rules

you send api services with 'action' and after success callback you call 'muation' with 'commit' and at last if you want to use it in any vue file you must call 'getters'

Comment: @AslanMuhammad-Rza This didn't work, it still gives the same array back as without the mutation